# What day is it today?

Tags: discussion, request-for-information

I've just hit the reputation cap (been a *long* time since I did that on MathOverflow) so all my incentives for answering or asking questions today have just defenestrated.

Flippancy aside, when is the "day" calculated from?  At what point can I start accumulating reputation again?

Comment: Seems to be UTC.

Comment: The day Starcraft 2 launches?

Comment: What's the cap? I want a badge =)

Comment: @Dima 200. See "What is reputation?" in the [faq](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: *Is* there actually a rep cap? Looking at my or especially ShreevatsaR’s reputation, I’d say no: the site has only existed for today and ShreevatsaR has already accumulated more rep than possible, even accounting for the accepted answer bonuses.

Comment: There definitely is a cap, I hit it today. I think what happened is that the private beta started just a few hours before midnight UTC, so the site's first "day" of existence was really only 3 or 4 hours long. And yet that was enough time for ShreevatsaR and maybe a couple others to hit the cap once. Now we're on the second UTC day.

Comment: @David: my point is that ShreevatsaR has *more* points than two days of rep-capping, plus all bonuses, allow. But I’ve just hit the rep cap too.

Comment: @Konrad: Ouch; my reputation is among the highest?! I should spend less time here. But note that we started with reputation of 101, not 0. I think at the end of the first day, my rep was probably 301.

Comment: I didn't start with 101 - I definitely started at 0!  I hit the rep cap at 215 (I guess that 15 or so didn't count in the count).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Duh. 101, right. All’s fine then.

Comment: @Andrew: As far as I know the 100 extra points are awarded to active users of the other Stack Exchange sites, i.e. when you associate your account with the accounts on other sites.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same as all the other sites, UTC. You can see the current time on the **Recent Activity** page (the envelope icon next to your name), at the bottom:

> all times are in UTC; the current time is 2010-07-27 17:42:32Z

See also: [When does a day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/when-does-a-day-start) on the SO meta